# Is $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ conformal to $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ conformal to $\mathbb{D}$?

I think so: All I need to prove is that $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a holomorphic and a bijection onto upper half plane. If so $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty) \sim \mathbb{H}\sim\mathbb{D}$.

we pick a branch of $\ln(z)$ $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Now it is clearly surjective. All I need to show is that is it injective. Let $a^{\frac{1}{2}}=b^{\frac{1}{2}}$ Then lengths have to be equal thus $|a|=|b|$ hence we only need to show that they have the same angle. We get that $\theta_a/2=\theta_b/2+2k\pi$ we know $k$ must be zero as otherwise we would have an angle outside of $[0,2\pi)$ Thus they have the same angle and so it is an injective map. Therfore, we are done! This clearly generalizes to $z^\frac{1}{n}$ and even any real number, correct?

Comment: Do you know Riemann Mapping Theorem?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is not simply connected though

Comment: $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$ is in fact simply connected.

Comment: Any region conformally equivalent to a simply connected region  is necessarily simply connected.( So the given region better be simply connected!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G = \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ is simply connected (the complement is connected) and not equal to the plane, and therefore conformally equivalent to the unit disk.

Your arguments are correct, but can be simplified if you go in the other direction:
$$
f: \Bbb H \to G, f(z) = z^2
$$
is holomorphic, surjective (I'll leave that part to you) and injective:
$$
 f(z) = f(w) \implies 0 = z^2-w^2 = (z-w)(z+w) \implies z=w
$$
because $z+w$ is in the upper half-plane and therefore cannot be zero.

An explicit mapping from the unit disk to $G$ can also be given in terms of the [Koebe function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem#Koebe_function) which maps the unit disk conformally to $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, -1/4 )$.